# Place text next to an image inside a bootstrap 5 row (col-sm-6)

Tags: html, css

I can't really explain it well, so here's some image.

This is what I currently have: https://prnt.sc/184ourg
This is what I want to get to: https://prnt.sc/184pfgt

This is basically the HTML:

```
<div class="row row-align">
    <div id="bg1" class="col-sm-6 background-1 rounded-corners maxheight">
        <img class="logoMaxSize rounded-corners" src="files/placeholder.png">
        <p>text</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Different classes:
`row` is the one used in Bootstrap 5
`row-align` is setting width to 100%, and margin-left to 0px
`#bg1` is unimportant here
`col-sm-6` the one used in Bootstrap 5
`background-1` just a gradient
`rounded-corners` sets border-radius to 15px
`maxheight` sets max-height to 100px
`logoMaxSize` sets the placeholder.png to 100px in width and height

Anything that I could do or try that would get me to basically the second image? The red vertical line doesn't have to be there, I basically just want the text (or the p tag) to show up next to the image while still inside the `col-sm-6`.

Comment: you can add class in `img` and `p` tags, e.g `class='col-sm-4'` each. Use 4 or else to make it fit. Why, since `col-md`,`col-sm`,`col-lg`,`col-xs` means `float:left` ---

Answer (score 0):

You can apply this class as the following.

```
<div class="row row-align **d-flex align-items-start**">
        <div id="bg1" class="col-sm-6 background-1 rounded-corners maxheight"  >
            <img class="logoMaxSize rounded-corners" src="files/placeholder.png">
            <p >text</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use bootstrap class to make it. You can also add new class (`txt1` in `p` tag), as in:

```
<div class="row row-align">
    <div id="bg1" class="col-sm-6 background-1 rounded-corners maxheight">
        <img class="logoMaxSize rounded-corners" src="joe_kdw.jpg" width="162" height="162">
        <p class="txt1">text</p> <!-- add new class, e.g. txt1 -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Add simple css:

```
img.logoMaxSize,p.txt1{float:left;}
```

[image]

Comment: It kind of works, not really but ehh
I could just use br tags though text is on the left of the img (assuming text overflows, it just get's all weird, https://prnt.sc/185ip6z.) 
My plan is to just redo how I want it to look, and avoid how I initially wanted to design it